# Use LongPressGesture to fire an action multiple time

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to fire an action once when using a TapGesture and multiple times when using LongPressGesture. The best example of what I want to do is the "Delete" key on the keyboard, when you long-press it, it continues removing the last character.

My question is how to replicate this behavior in SwiftUI.

For the moment, I came up with this solution (which doesn't work):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var longPress: some Gesture {
        LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 3)
            .onChanged({ (bool) in
                guard bool else {
                    self.timer?.invalidate()
                    return
                }
                
                self.timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: true) { (timer) in
                     action() // Fired every 0.2 seconds until the user stop pressing
                }
            })
    }
    
    @State var timer: Timer? = nil

    var body: some View {
        Subview()
            .onTapGesture {
                action() // Fired once
            }
            .gesture(longPress)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var timer: Timer?

    var body: some View {
        Text("Tap me")
            .onTapGesture {
                self.action()
            }
            .gesture(
                LongPressGesture()
                    .onEnded { _ in // fired when `LongPressGesture` is detected
                        print("start...")
                        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: true) { _ in
                            self.action()
                        }
                    }
                    .sequenced(before:
                        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                print("end...")
                                self.timer?.invalidate()
                                self.timer = nil
                            }
                    )
            )
    }

    func action() {
        print("action...")
    }
}
```